# CAPTCHA - what domain is it coming from?

Tags: support, status-completed, captcha

I got caught by the captcha.  However, I can't fill it out because our whitelist firewall is blocking it.  What domain(s) do I have to add to get the captcha phrase and entry boxes to show up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CAPTCHA is provided by [`http://www.google.com/recaptcha`](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll get that added

Answer (score 4):

It depends but if it's reCaptcha try these:

recaptcha.net
api.recaptcha.net